# Вложенный запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю вложенный запрос в бд, по идее все правильно, и даже все выводит отлично но при этом записи дублируются 10 раз, вот мой код:

```
<?php 
//вывода json для раздела url

include('../db.php');

$login = $_GET['login'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

$arr = array(); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_password, user_login FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
while($userdata = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($login == $userdata['user_login'] & md5(md5($pass)) == $userdata['user_password']) {
        @mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT bm_url, bm_title, notes FROM urls, notes WHERE urls.user_id = '".$userdata['user_id']."' and notes.user_id = '".$userdata['user_id']."'") or die ("Синтаксис хромает типуля"); 
        while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
            $arr[] = $obj; 
        } 
        $json = '{"urls":'.json_encode($arr).'}'; 
        echo $json; 
    }
}
?>
```

Что тут не так? По идее должно выводить по одной записи )

**UPD**
таблица users

```
user_id | user_login | user_password
```

таблица urls

```
id | user_id | bm_url | bm_title
```

таблица notes

```
id | user_id | notes
```

user_id - дублируется из таблицы users в остальные при регистрации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не вложенный запрос. Вообще логика странная. Выбрать всех пользователей, пройтись по ним всем, если пользователь текущий - отдать его заметки и ссылки, потом продолжить проход по пользователям...

Почему бы не обойтись одним запросом?

```
<?php

  $arr   = array();
  $login = $_GET['login'];
  $pass  = md5( md5( $_GET['pass'] ) );

  // Проверки введенных данных!

  $query = " SELECT u.bm_url, 
                    u.bm_title, 
                    n.notes
               FROM urls AS u, 
                    notes AS n,
                    users AS i
              WHERE n.user_id       = '$login'
                AND u.user_id       = '$login'
                AND i.user_login    = '$login' 
                AND i.user_password = '$password' ";

  $q = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );

  while( $i = mysql_fetch_array( $q ) ) {
    $arr[] = $i; 
  }

  echo '{"urls":' . json_encode($arr) . '}';
```

Засада, я так чувствую, в соотношении данных. Если одной заметке соответствует несколько ссылок (или наоборот), то данные дублируются. Примерно, так:

*urls*:

```
id | id_user | bm_url | bm_title 
---|---------|--------|---------
 1 |       1 | url1   | title1 
 2 |       1 | url1   | title1 
 3 |       1 | url1   | title1
```

*notes*:

```
id | id_user | notes 
---|---------|----------
 1 |       1 | note1 
 2 |       1 | note2 
 3 |       1 | note3
```

В итоге имеем:

```
bm_url | bm_title | notes
-------|----------|------
url1   | title1   | note1
url2   | title2   | note1 
url3   | title3   | note1
url1   | title1   | note2
url2   | title2   | note2 
url3   | title3   | note2
url1   | title1   | note3
url2   | title2   | note3 
url3   | title3   | note3
```

Если точно нужно обойтись одним запросом, можно сделать так:

```
  $query = " SELECT 'url' AS type,
                    u.bm_url AS f1, 
                    u.bm_title AS f2 
               FROM urls AS u, 
                    users AS i
              WHERE u.user_id       = '$login'
                AND i.user_login    = '$login' 
                AND i.user_password = '$password'
       UNION SELECT 'note' AS type,
                    '' AS f1, 
                    n.notes AS f2 
               FROM notes AS n, 
                    users AS i
              WHERE n.user_id       = '$login'
                AND i.user_login    = '$login' 
                AND i.user_password = '$password' ";

type |  f1  | f2
-----|------|--------
url  | url1 | title1
url  | url2 | title2 
url  | url3 | title3
note |      | note1
note |      | note2 
note |      | note3
```

Comment: откуда взялись u, n, i ? что это?

Выдает Unknown column 'dajver' in 'where clause'

Comment: Кавычек не хватает. Поправил.

Comment: так же дублируются)

Comment: Дайте пример данных. То, что соответствует 1 пользователю в таблицах urls и notes.

Comment: обновил свой вопрос. 

Ваш запрос выдает You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM urls AS u, users AS i WHERE u.user_id ' at line 4

Я так понял лучше другой подход искать... И выводить разные джсоны в разных файлах под разные данные...

Comment: Это я опять поторопился и не убрал запятые перед WHERE. А вот насчет разделения - это правильное направление мысли. Собственно из-за попытки собрать все в одном месте и получаются повторы (об этом я в ответе и написал).